# Select values from multiple rows from 1 table as 1 record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm struggling to even explain what I need to do so please be patient with me.
I have the following table and rows in it:

TBNAME: **`Distances`**

## Track, Person, Date, Distance

```
TRACK1, P1, 1/1/2014, 15
TRACK2, P1, 13/1/2014, 12
TRACK1, P1, 20/2/2014, 10
TRACK2, P1, 15/1/2014, 9
TRACK1, P2, 2/1/2014, 11
TRACK2, P2, 14/1/2014, 13
TRACK1, P2, 21/2/2014, 8
TRACK2, P2, 16/1/2014, 6
```

What I would, ideally, like to see as a result is something like this:

```
P1, TRACK1, 20/2/2014, 10, TRACK2, 15/1/2014, 9
P2, TRACK1, 21/2/2014, 8, TRACK2, 16/1/2014, 6
```

Or, in other words, for each person,  the most recent date and distance for that date for each track in one row.

Hope someone can understand this and offer a solution too :)

Cheers,
Pierre

Comment: U need to order the data by person and date thats it

Comment: As SQL queries always return a before-known number of columns, you can only do this in SQL when you know how many tracks there are. Do you? Is it always just these two, TRACK1 and TRACK2? Easiest would be anyhow to let SQL give you the raw records needed (four records in your example) and use a programming language to display columns instead of rows in your GUI.

Comment: Big Thanks to everyone who replied. I appreciate the pure effort you all put in, trying to reply to my question guys. I'll try to answer each of your questions / suggestions. Yes, there will always be only 2 tracks. No, I cannot use any programming language. It needs to be a SQL query that gives the result. It cannot be dynamic sql. PIVOT may be considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT    T1.Person, T1.Track, MAX(T1.Date), MIN(T1.Distance), 
          T2.Track, MAX(T2.Date), MIN(T2.Distance)
FROM      Distances AS T1 INNER JOIN
          Distances AS T2 ON T1.Person = T2.Person
WHERE     T1.Track <> T2.Track AND T1.Track = 'Track1'
GROUP BY  T1.Track, T1.Person, T2.Track
```

The output result of the query is showing exactly the same of your expected result.

Comment: Thank you Jesuraja. This is exactly what I needed. Good on you mate!

Answer (score 0):

Try combining the table by itself and connecting them with the common column.

In your case you want `Person`.

```
Select t1.Person, 
       t1.Tract, 
       t1.Date, 
       t1.Distance,
       t2.Tract, 
       t2.date, 
       t2.Distance 
From table_name t1, table_name t2
WHERE t1.Person = t2.Person;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("Person", "Track") *
FROM   "Table"
ORDER  BY "Person", "Date" DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms186734%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and [`OVER PARITION BY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms189461%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Idea is something like (I did not try to run this query):

```
;WITH
  data AS
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      -- returns number for each pair of person and track starting from most recent date
      --Code enhanced at here
      row_number() over (partition BY person, track order by dte DESC) nr 
    FROM distances
  ) 
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    data
  WHERE
    nr = 1 -- we want just the most recent one
  ORDER BY
    person, -- "group by" person
    track ;
```

It's still doesn't support showing one row for each person...
I don't think you can do it with SQL (because of unknown number of tracks).

There is [`PIVOT/UNPIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), but I don't think it fits here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query to get the records needed. First get the maximum date per track and person. Then join with the table to get the complete record.

If you know beforehand which tracks you will get, you can use a pivot query for this. As I've never done this, I ask you to look this up yourself. However, as mentioned in my comment to your request, I would use a programming language (C#, Java, PHP or whatever) to care about that.

```
select d.track, d.person, d.date, d.distance
from
(
  select track, person, max(distances.date) as `date`
  from distances
  group by track, person
) lastd
inner join distances d on d.track = lastd.track and d.person = lastd.person and d.date = lastd.date
order by d.track, d.person;
```

BTW: date is a reserved keyword. I would not recommend to use it for a column name. Whenever you use it without a qualifier you will have to use those strange quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
Select P1.Track,P1.Person,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by Person,Track Order by Date         

Desc) AS RN1 
,Date,Distance
from Distances P1
)Select T.Person,T.Track1,T.T1Date
,T.T1Distance,T.Track2,T.T2Date,T.T2Distance 
From (
Select C1.Person,C1.Track AS 'Track1',C1.Date AS 'T1Date',
C1.Distance 'T1Distance', 
C2.Track AS 'Track2',C2.Date As 'T2Date',C2.Distance 'T2Distance',
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY C1.Person Order by C1.Date Desc) RNX 
from 
CTE C1 
JOIN 
CTE C2 ON C1.RN1=1 AND C2.RN1=1
AND C1.Person=C2.Person
AND C1.Track<>C2.Track
)t Where t.RNX=1
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a general query it need to be dynamic

```
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @pivotCols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @pivotCols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME([Track])
                      FROM Distances
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') , 1, 1, '')
;WITH T AS (
  SELECT Track
       , _ID = CAST(Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY Track) AS VARCHAR)
  FROM   Distances
  GROUP BY Track
)
SELECT @Cols = STUFF((
       SELECT ', Track_' + _ID + ' = ''' + Track + ''''
            + ', LastRun_' + _ID + ' = ' + QUOTENAME([Track])
            + ', Distance_' + _ID + ' 
               = SUM(CASE WHEN d.Date = ' + QUOTENAME([Track]) + ' 
                           AND d.Track = ''' + Track + ''' 
                          THEN d.Distance ELSE NULL END)'
                      FROM T FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') , 1, 1, '')
SELECT @query = '
With LR AS (
  SELECT Person, ' + @pivotCols + '
  FROM   (SELECT Track, Person, [Date] FROM   Distances) d
         PIVOT (MAX([Date]) FOR Track IN (' + @pivotCols + ')) pvt
)
SELECT d.Person, ' + @Cols + '
FROM   Distances d
       INNER JOIN LR ON d.Person = LR.Person AND d.Date IN (' + @pivotCols + ')
GROUP BY d.Person, ' + @pivotCols + ''

execute(@query);
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58734/1)</kbd>

The first query generate the list of field for the `PIVOT`.
The second one generate the fields for the compound query.

The `PIVOT` is used to get, for every person, the last run on every track, that is than joined back to the base data to get the distance

Answer (score 0):

you may also use dynamic query to achieve your expected result :)

```
DECLARE @nCount INT 
DECLARE @nStart INT
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) =' '
DECLARE @sPerson NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sTrack NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @nCount = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(person)) FROM DISTANCES)

SET @nStart = 1

WHILE @nStart <= @nCount
BEGIN

SET @sPerson = (SELECT PERSON FROM (
SELECT PERSON, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PERSON) RN FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT(PERSON) FROM DISTANCES
) T1 
) T2 WHERE RN = @nStart
)


SET @Query = @Query + ' 
SELECT '''+@sPerson+''' + '','' + STUFF( '','' +(
SELECT TRACK + '', '' + DATE + '', '' + DISTANCE FROM (
SELECT TRACK, DATE,DISTANCE, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TRACK ORDER BY DATE DESC) RN FROM (
SELECT TRACK,date,DISTANCE FROM DISTANCES WHERE PERSON = '''+@sPerson+'''
) T1 
) T2
WHERE RN = 1 FOR XML PATH('''')
),1,1,''''
)
'
IF(@nStart != @nCount)
SET @Query = @Query + ' UNION ALL '

SET @nStart = @nStart + 1

END

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Query
```